# Store variable from one event handler to be used by another event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#open").click(function()
{
 var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
 /* the next lines of code affects the value
  * of 'pos'.
  */
});

$("#close").click(function()
{
 var pos = /* what i want here is the $(window).scrollTop(); 
            before the #open event handler changes it's value. */
 //another code of mine.
});
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well for one, your functions have no `()` on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very simple, make variable global

```
var pos; //global variable
$("#open").click(function()
{
 pos = $(window).scrollTop();
 /* the next lines of code affects the value
  * of 'pos'.
  */
});

$("#close").click(function()
{
 // use pos here accordingly
 //another code of mine.
});
```

Comment: or put it in an IIFE so it isn't global

Answer (score 1):

You can store the original `window` DOM contents before you call any functions:

```
var pos;

$("#open").click(function(){
    pos = $(window).scrollTop();
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $(window).height(pos);
});
```

> Docs

- http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/
- http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 1):

```
You could just organize a little your code and do this:

function MyApp(){
   var self = this;

   this.pos = "";
   this.temp = $(window).scrollTop();   //store initial value 

   this.wire = function(){
      $("#open").click(self.open);
      $("#close").click(self.close);
   }

   this.open = function(){
     self.pos = $(window).scrollTop();
      /* the next lines of code affects the value
       * of 'pos'.
       */
   }

   this.close = function(){
     self.pos = /* what i want here is the $(window).scrollTop(); before
            * the #open event handler changes it's value.
            */
        //another code of mine.
     var original = self.temp;  //here get the initial stored value
   }


}
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var app = new MyApp();
        app.wire();         //wire handlers
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you want your `var pos` one level higher?

Comment: seems like global variable can take care of my problem as mentioned by @Arun, but anyways, thanks for giving an answer, very much appreciated :)

Comment: @muistooshort: I don't see why storing pos one level higher?

Comment: I thought the intention was to communicate the `scrollTop()` between the `#open` and `#close` handlers so you need the same `pos` to be visible to both functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a variable local to an anonymous function:

```
(function() {
    var context = {};
    $('#open').click(function() {
        context.pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
    $('#close').click(function() {
        // Do something with context.pos
    });
})();
```

Your code and explanation don't make this clear, but the above maintains an assumption from your code: That close cannot be clicked unless open has been clicked, and open cannot be clicked again until close has been clicked. But that really depends on your code - if that assumption isn't true I'd approach it differently (if that assumption isn't true, clicking close here risks getting an undefined).

Comment: #close is inside a dialogbox (which is shown by clicking #open).
:)
thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

More safe way.

```
 $("#open").click(function() {
            $("#close").attr("data-pop", $(window).scrollTop());

        });

        $("#close").click(function() {
            var pos = $(this).attr("data-pop");
        });
```

Comment: Why use a non-standard attribute when we have access to standard HTML5 data attributes?

Comment: it is not non-standard attribute. It is called custom attribute.

Comment: Can you quote anything in the HTML standard that says that `<div pop="6"></div>` is valid HTML? Why not simply say `$('#close').data('pop', ...)` instead and stay nicely within the standards?

Comment: You should do 'data-pop' instead.

Comment: It is Custom Attribute.There are lots of framework that adds custome attributes like Validation Framework in MVC adds data-val attributes.So You are free to add Custom Attributes as per your need and It is a Valid HTML. @Daniel... naming like data-pop is about naming convention.It has nothing to do with its validity.

Comment: Nonsense. http://validator.w3.org/ says otherwise and `data-` attributes are **not** just a naming convention: [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) You need to learn the difference between standards and what your tools do.

Comment: @Priyank: If w3c comes along in 2, 5, 10 years and creates an attribute with the same name. Now your page is broken.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. It should be data-pop.I have edited the answer.